# Using module constructor and async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I cannot figure out how to keep the constructor scope or whatever ever you want to call it, it simply gets replaced with the global variables.

I will be calling multiple functions and each will generate different data and will set different variables;

How can I solve this?

```
function Foo(user, data) {
    this.user = user;
    this.data = data;
}
Foo.prototype.init = function(callback) {
    async.series([
        this.functionOne,
    ], function(err, result) {
        callback(err, []);
    });
};
Foo.prototype.functionOne = function(callback) {
    console.log(this);
    this.username = "abc";
    callback(null);
}
module.exports = Foo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to preserve the `this` value when you pass a method reference by using `.bind()`:

```
function Foo(user, data) {
    this.user = user;
    this.data = data;
}
Foo.prototype.init = function(callback) {
    async.series([
        // add `.bind(this)` here to preserve value of this
        // when the function is called by async
        this.functionOne.bind(this),
    ], function(err, result) {
        callback(err, []);
    });
};
Foo.prototype.functionOne = function(callback) {
    console.log(this);
    this.username = "abc";
    callback(null);
}
module.exports = Foo;
```

Although, there is no reason to use the async library if you only have one async function to execute.

---

When you pass `this.functionOne` to the async library, all that is passed is a reference to the `functionOne` method.  No association with `this` is preserved.  Thus, when the async library calls that method later, the value of `this` will be wrong.  You can use `.bind()` to "bind" the correct value of `this` to a new temporary stub function that you then pass to async and then when your method gets called, it will have the correct value of `this`.